# Skpsmtpmessage: which server should i use for gmail

Tags: iphone, email

I got this project "skpsmtpmessage" and I tried to send mail first. So I changed all the mail id to gmail id. But replay host is problem. I tried smtp.gmail.com, smtp.google.com, smtp.googletalk.com. But when I run my program, I get error that "Unable to connect server"

Which relay host should I use for gmail.

Answer (score 1):

The correct SMTP server for Gmail is `smtp.gmail.com`, but I don't know how to help you further, the question is pretty vague.

You can also take a look at the [configuration instructions](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77702) for using Gmail on the iPhone to see if you're making a mistake with another parameter.